# K-means and maximum likelihood!

Tags: classification, clustering, maximum-likelihood, k-means, unsupervised-learning

Is there any relation between k-means and the maximum-likelihood estimate in unsupervised learning? Any references would be appreciates!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried interpreting k-means as EM algorithm already?

Comment: That was the idea.... I read about EM can be view as k-means generalization... But I can't find any proof. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's actually rather straightforward... first, have a look at e.g. Mclust in R, which is the R implementation of EM, and understand the model parameter; in particular the `E` model.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Thank you so much!

Comment: No, I don't want to spoil the fun for you. The basic relationship is really straightforward, you just need to look closely at the two methods.

Comment: No fun when you are in a hurry :D

Answer (score 3):

You can think as K-Means as EM Algorithm (With Hard Thresholding) for GMM.
Since EM is a method for Maximum Likelihood Estimation you have a connection.